# Get a PHP variable from a page to another with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got two pages:

**1.php** and **2.php**

I'm trying to get a PHP variable from 2.php to 1.php through an AJAX request.

This is the script in 1.php

```
<script>
    jQuery('#refresh').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '2.php',
            data: { variable: '<?php echo $PHPvariable ?>' },
            dataType : 'json',
            success:function(response){
                alert(variable);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

For your better understanding, this script is called from within the 1.php file.
As you can see I'm trying to retreive the $PHPvariable variable declared in 2.php.
Am I doing it correctly??

This is the varialbe delcaration in 2.php

```
$PHPvariable = 'bla1bla2bla';
$variable = array('PHPvariable ' => $PHPvariable );
echo json_encode($variable);
```

What is wrong ??

Comment: You are in 1.php so $PHPVariable must be declared in 1.php, not in 2.php. In 2.php you can retrieve this variable using $_POST['variable']

Comment: Sorry maybe I explained myself wrong: I need to do just the opposite!
While being on 1.php

Comment: Is this possible to get PHP in JS? like `data: { variable: '<?php echo $PHPvariable ?>' },`

Comment: @Ranjith yes if you are spitting the JS out of a PHP file.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker : Could you provide any reference example link?

Comment: @Alexvan yes all you need to do is then instead of `alert`ing the variable, do another `ajax` back to PHP1 with the variable you got from `php2`

Comment: @Ranjith http://pastebin.com/2tpAsV0g it really is basic PHP coding.

Comment: To be fair, this whole thing is moot if you're not doing cross-domain requests between 1 and 2 as you can just get the variable in PHP straight without needing to touch javascript!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I need to to it this way, because I'm handling a session variable which is constantly changing into 2.php ...
But let's remain on topic :) So how should I retrieve it correctly ??

Comment: @Ghost that question is pending to be deleted, so please don't link it in here.

Answer (score 0):

in 2.php the `variable` (POST using JS) can be accessed using `$_POST['variable'];` (in PHP).

`sessionVar` (JS) in 1.php is undefined (JS), data can be accessed by `response.sessionVar` (JS) (from `success:function(response){`).

In 2.php you have to print the data like `echo json_encode(array('sessionVar' => $sessionVar));` (PHP).

Update: To prevent confusion I pointed out wether the code parts are PHP or JS.

Update:

You can't expose data **and** a binary image in a response as there is no multipart response in common HTTP (not sure about SPDY). Either expose an image OR data, not both.

What you can do is to base64 encode the image and output the image as part of the data:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'image' => base64_encode($image),
    'variable' => $someVariable),
);
```

A different approach is not to use ajax but use phps `include('2.php');` instead, then the variable is available in 1.php.

Comment: Sorry, you don't get it :P
I'm trying to get a $PHPvariable from 2.php to 1.php throught an AJAX request launched from 1.php
And then alert it. (Just fixed the wrong alert call)

Comment: @Alexvan I got it, don't worry. In 2.php you have to echo the json encoded `$PHPvariable`.

Comment: Sure now delete my comments and excuse for incovenience

Comment: @Alexvan the alert call is still wrong

Comment: So this is what i wrote in the 2.php file
**echo json_encode(array('variable' => $PHPvariable));**

so how am i returning it into the 1.php ???
the alert is just to test it

Comment: @Alexvan you return it by the `echo` and you retreive it by `success:function(response)`, your alert is wrong! You can't test with it because `variable` is **`undefined`**. Use `alert(response)` or `console.debug(response)`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, ok I modified the alert and added the console.debug as you suggested. But the script is not working still :( So the problem is into something else...

Comment: @Alexvan what does 2.php output when you open it in the browser ? (without ajax etc) Can you see the request through the browsers console? (ctrl+shift+i)

Comment: The 2.php is a file that generates an image with the **imagettftext** function. So the source is interpreted as an image by the **header('Content-Type: image/png');**
This file sets a variable as well, I need to get that variable in 1.php...

Comment: @Alexvan dude.... that's not possible, there is nothing like "multipart" response. I update my answer.

Comment: Hum I was afraid of that, so do you have any clues on how to return that variable?
I tried to set it as session variable. That works. But 2.php each time it's called generates a new variable that I want to be passed, so if I echo the session variable in 1.php the page itself loads the 2.php page which generates a new variable. And the previously echoed one is wrong...
Sorry for the big mess...

Answer (score 0):

> For your better understanding, this script is called from within the
>   1.php file. As you can see I'm trying to retreive the $PHPvariable variable declared in 2.php. Am I doing it correctly??

For passing variable from `1.php` and `2.php` you have to use the `form`.

This is a example for the login user

```
<form action="2.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            username:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="userName">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="invio" value="login">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now inside the file `2.php` you verification the variable passing.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if (isset($_POST['invio']))
    if (empty($_POST['userName']) || empty($_POST['password']))
        $messaggio = "dati mancanti";
    else {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userName']  = $_POST['userName'];
        $_SESSION['dataLogin'] = time();
        $_SESSION['ruolo']     = $ruolo[0];

        $messaggio = '<p> <h1 style="color:red">Benvenuto </h1> </p>';


        ;
    }

?>
```

Now you can print (always inside the page `2.php`) the result of message:

```
<?php
echo $messaggio;
echo $_POST['userName'];
?>
```

And for return in the page 1.php you can with:

```
  <?php
header('Location: 1.php');
?>
```

Inside the script of php.

If you want to use AJAX and without refreshing page I think that you want [this exercise](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp)

And I suggest for you case this:

```
var value="your value"
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.asp?q="+value,true);
```

And on `gething.php`

```
 <?php
//get the q parameter from URL
 $q=$_GET["q"];

 //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
 if (strlen($q) > 0)
 {
  echo $q;
}else{
 echo "miss value";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @MirkoCianfarani, what I'm trying to do is free from forms use.

Comment: Excuse but I not understand you sentence....

Comment: Mirko, sono italiano anche io, sto cercando di passare una variabile da una pagina ad un'altra senza l'uso di form.
--
Mirko, I'm Italian as well, I'm trying to pass a variable from a page to another without using forms.

Comment: ahahha non puoi!!! You can't.
You can add on skype or other with my e-mail mrk1989@hotmail.it

Comment: Look the update answer